# Find the value of $T(x^3)$ and $T(x^4)$ where $T:V\to\mathbb R$ is a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Question: Let $V$ be the real vector space consisting of all polynomials in one variable with real coefficients and having degree at most 5, together with zero polynomial. Let $T:V\to\mathbb R$ be a linear map defined by $T(1)=1$ and $T(x(x-1)\dots (x-k+1))=1$ for $1\leq k\leq 5$. Then find the value of $T(x^3)$ and $T(x^4)$.

My Attempt:

We have that $V$={$p(x):  deg(p(x))\leq 5$}, also its a vector space along with the zero polynomial . To find the value of $T(x^3)$ and $T(x^4)$, I expanded the expression under the map $T$ but I wasn't getting any conclusion from there.Any hint to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: You know $T(p)$ for some values of $p$. You’ll need to write the polynomials you’re interested in as linear combinations of those. A good warmup would be to determine $T(x^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dim(V) =6$

Basis $\mathcal{B}=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}$

$T(1) =1$

For $k=1$, $T(x) =1$

For $k=2$ ,$T(x(x-1)) =1$

$\implies T(x^2) -Tx=1$

i.e $T(x^2) =2$

For $k=3$ , $T(x^3) -3T(x^2) +2T(x) =1$

$\implies T(x^3) =5$